# Telegram Bot messages

Tags: telegram-bot

Is it possible that bots send messages in chats only to specific members, and the messages aren't visible for other members of the chat?

For example:
There is a chat with 200 members and the bot is one of them. Somebody sends a command /help and bot responds only to him and others don't see the response

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this at this time, but there are [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) method you might interested.

And there are [inline keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating) can ask users to START your bot, just put `https://t.me/Bot` as URL value.